# USQL Extract subset of files

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a USQL question. I have a daily job that is outputting files to a directory in the following format

/MyOutput/{YYYY}/{MM}/{DD}/file.csv

I have a second job now that I want to run that will use the most recent 30 files produced by the first job. I can't figure out how to best do this though.

I know I can do wildcards in the extractor but I prefer not to extract all files and then use a select/where to remove the ones I don't want as extracting all files could get really costly if I'm keeping years worth of these files.

So is there a nice way in usql to say extract only the most recent x files? Or what options do I have here?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a date pattern it will do what you want.

```
@rows = 
    EXTRACT 
      ...,
      date DateTime
    FROM /MyOutput/{date:YYYY}/{date:MM}/{date:dd}/file.csv;

SELECT * FROM @rows WHERE date > '2018-5-3'
```

Will read only the files matching the date range - it won't read all of them in first.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I didn't realize it would be that smart about it.